# Infinite scroll pattern, while not breaking 'Find [text on page]' action

Tags: ajax, browser, scroll, find

Any ideas/tips/answers on how to keep the browser's `Find [text on page]` functionality while implementing Infinite Scroll, especially with a text subject matter entries (e.g. Facebook wall, or a blog that infinite scroll displays posts...).

I can't recall an event for onFind or such. I guess you could watch for the keystroke, but that would break menu driven Find. Clearly a search form would be straight forward, but not always the intuitive answer... *Users expect to 'search', say, the entire site, or at least beyond the current page, while /Cmd|Ctrl/-F the current page they're looking at...* With infinite scroll the concept of 'the page' is entirely broken, more so than even dynamic content through XHR.